# mixing 4GB and 8GB RAM chips on LENOVO V320 i7-8550U 8G/256 DVD 17.3" fHD W10Pro 81CN0002IX

Tags: memory

I am about to buy a brand new LENOVO
V320 i7-8550U 8G/256 DVD 17.3" fHD W10Pro 81CN0002IX from a local shop
and wanted to upgrade to 16GB of RAM.

The guys at the shop said there was no problem, only to discover, when they opened the machine, that 4GB were solded, not removable as the other 4GB.

They proposed to upgrade anyway (actually, thay have already done the work), just replacing the removable 4 with an 8GB, totalling 12GB instead of 16GB.

What would you suggest me to do? Did anyone do such a replacement on that machine model? Any problems?

I need RAM in order to write Oracle software  (ADF, BI Publisher 
and PL-SQL), compiling locally (database is on server).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find a manual for for your model (shame on Lenovo Support).
So I asked
[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/lenovo-v320)
what are the possible RAM upgrades for the V320.

The results that came back on the page
[Lenovo Lenovo V320 compatible upgrades](https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Lenovo/lenovo-v320)
had 8 GB as the maximum.
So apparently the maximum possible is 12 GB, and you cannot go higher
with this model.

If this is not enough and it is still possible to cancel the command,
then you may do so.
Whether 12 GB are enough or not depends on your
workload and runtime parameters, so I cannot comment on it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and… it looks even worse than I imagined.
On Crucial site  they state:
V320
Slots: 1 (1 bank of 1)
Maximum Memory: 8GB
*Not to exceed manufacturer supported memory.
Standard Memory: 2GB to 8GB removable

for V320IKB e V320ISK only they state

Slots: 2 (2 banks of 1)
Maximum Memory: 32GB
*Not to exceed manufacturer supported memory.
Standard Memory: 8GB removable

No reference to the solded, unchangeable slot.

Aaaargh!

Comment: They will not refer to the unchangeable slot because they are selling upgrades, and this one cannot be upgraded. They don't offer more than 8 GB for this computer, probably for a reason. If you want to be sure, download their scanner from the home page - it is very accurate for hardware analysis.